# VirtualBox 5.1 on Ubuntu Server 17.10

Tags: server, virtualbox, 17.10

Hi recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 17.04 and virtualbox on it and then ran the **do-release-upgrade** command to upgrade to 17.10.

I now end up getting the following error, is it because of the kernel version or something else? At this point of time virtualbox's website suggested the latest download being available for Ubutu 17.04 :(

```
-- Unit virtualbox.service has begun starting up.
Oct 28 14:55:31 ares virtualbox[902]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Oct 28 14:55:31 ares virtualbox[902]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Oct 28 14:55:31 ares virtualbox[902]:    ...fail!
Oct 28 14:55:31 ares systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 28 14:55:31 ares systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
-- Subject: Unit virtualbox.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit virtualbox.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

**apt list virtualbox** gives the following output:

```
Listing... Done
virtualbox/artful,now 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64 [installed]
```

reinstalled vbox still get the following (when installing):

```
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-10-28 16:25:50 CEST; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4586 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 26ms

Oct 28 16:25:50 ares systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares virtualbox[4586]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares virtualbox[4586]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares virtualbox[4586]:    ...fail!
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 28 16:25:50 ares systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: I see `virtualbox/artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1` on `apt search` so how did you get that version?

Comment: If I recollect correctly, I had installed virtualbox on 17.04 and then ran the release-upgrade. I'll edit/update the question to reflect the same

Comment: @George I would assume via download from [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Comment: @Kunal Can you append your question with the output of `apt list virtualbox`

Comment: @CharlesGreen done

Comment: Just scrolling thru Mine works fine on 17.10 and get this....virtualbox/artful,now 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: Can you run `sudo vboxconfig` and apprend the output of this command to your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I get a command not found for vboxconfig, is the installation corrupt for me?

Comment: I don't think so (probably a bad command on my part - I use KVM/QEMU).  I am tempted to tell you to reinstall VirtualBox:  `sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I purged and reinstalled virtualbox but still the same issue (I've updated the logs too)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I think my issue might be that I seem to be running **4.13.0-16-lowlatency** kernel for some weird reason

Comment: 2 questions:  Have you examined "systemctl  status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl  -xe", and are you running Secure boot in your BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for some reason during the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 the kernel got switched from **4.13.0-16-generic** to **4.13.0-16-lowlatency**. It could be due to the fact that I ran the upgrade over ssh client instead of on the system itself. I did not investigate further as to why this happened. Since this was a new machine, I wiped it clean and installed 17.04 and upgraded to 17.10 on the terminal itself.